# My PHP mail() doesn't work

Tags: php, unix, sendmail, postfix-mta

I'm having a big headache because PHP mail() funcion does not work. I've already reinstalled the postfix app, but still no change!
If I do a telnet to localhost in port 25, I can send mails from the command line

```
root@server:/etc/postfix# telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 myserver.com.br ESMTP Postfix
ehlo
401 Syntax: EHLO hostname
ehlo localhost
250-myserver.com.br
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
mail from: info@myserver.com.br
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to: testes@gmail.com
250 2.1.5 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Subject: Ola

Boas t     
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as A71558AB472
```

I have installed the Zpanel before, don't really know if it's this what's messing with PHP mail... What else can it be?

The PHP mail() function I'm using is very simple and works on other servers:

```
mail("testes@hotmail.com","Tell","and","FROM: info@myserver.com.br\n\n");
```

The error Log that I get is something like this:

```
Nov 19 15:28:43 myserver postfix/pickup[6186]: 89B898AB477: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Nov 19 15:28:43 myserver postfix/cleanup[6630]: 89B898AB477: message-id=<20131119172843.89B898AB477@myserver.com.br>
Nov 19 15:28:43 myserver postfix/qmgr[6187]: 89B898AB477: from=<www-data@myserver.com.br>, size=361, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 19 15:28:44 myserver postfix/smtp[6634]: 89B898AB477: to=<testes@hotmail.com>, relay=mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.37.120]:25, delay=0.99, delays=0.17/0.01/0.6/0.2, dsn=4.0.0, status=SOFTBOUNCE (host mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.37.120] said: 550 SC-001 (COL0-MC4-F39) Unfortunately, messages from 201.33.21.60 weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list. You can also refer your provider to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
Nov 19 15:28:44 myserver postfix/smtp[6634]: 89B898AB477: lost connection with mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.37.120] while sending RCPT TO
```

EDIT : Figured out now that I can send this email to another server, but somehow Hotmail is blocking it.

Comment: Can you show us the `mail()` code and any errors / excerpt from the logs?

Comment: There it is: _Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list_  The host you're sending from is in one of the spam block lists, and the recipient server (hotmail) won't accept messages from it.  If this is a shared host, it's a pretty common predicament. Someone else on the shared host is sending spammy mail and it affects you too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that **hotmail** does not like envelope sender `www-data@myserver.com.br`(used in `MAIL FROM:`)

Use telnet to find out if hotmail is ready to accept messages from your host with another envelope sender address (www-data may be disliked/blocked).

If you configure php mail to send using sendmail program (postfix provides such program too) then you may set another envelope sender.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that hotmail is blocking my messages... I tried to send some messages to GMAIL and the first one came out OK.
The next emails I got the following logs

```
Nov 20 09:26:31 Server postfix/smtp[11729]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400c:c02::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Nov 20 09:26:32 Server postfix/smtp[11729]: 5A2238AB497: to=<teste@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.68.26]:25, delay=1.8, delays=0.17/0/1/0$
Nov 20 09:26:32 Server postfix/qmgr[7005]: 5A2238AB497: removed
Nov 20 09:28:20 Server postfix/smtpd[12027]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov 20 09:28:20 Server postfix/trivial-rewrite[12029]: warning: do not list domain myserver.com.br in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Nov 20 09:28:20 Server postfix/smtpd[12027]: ACCD08AB497: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Nov 20 09:28:20 Server postfix/cleanup[12031]: ACCD08AB497: message-id=<1384946900.528c9cd49418a@www.myserver.com.br>
Nov 20 09:28:20 Server postfix/qmgr[7005]: ACCD08AB497: from=<info@myserver.com.br>, size=1260, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 20 09:28:20 Server postfix/smtpd[12027]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
```

And after some search I figured out the problem was on ipv6 configurations, so I edited postfix/main.cf and the line inet_protocols = All to inet_protocols = ipv4.

The new output is something like this

```
Nov 20 09:54:49 Server postfix/smtp[12315]: 70A3A8AA103: to=<teste@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.68.27]:25, delay=2, delays=0.21/0/0.4/1.4, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1384948492 d5si7115120qcj.49 - gsmtp)
Nov 20 09:54:49 Server postfix/qmgr[12243]: 70A3A8AA103: removed
```

But this recipient didn't get his emails, although the OK status :(

Answer (score 0):

You may refer on these links to have your IP address remove from Hotmail black list

https://sender.office.com/

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&wfname=capsub&productkey=edfsmsbl3&locale=en-us&wa=wsignin1.0&ccsid=635965844486152513